# how to call cocos2d-js method from objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

i am using cocos2d-js , that's a in purchase app,when purchase success ,i need to notify the message to cocos2d-js to update ui or something else,

i know call objective-c from cocos2d-js is like:
in js:

```
jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("objective-cClass","methodName:", "parm");
```

but,how to call cocos2d-js from objective-c...

Comment: sorry for the format  main method:  jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod

Comment: Following link will be helpful . Good luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c

Comment: Go through this link https://github.com/zynga/jsbindings it explains everything whatever you needed

Answer (score 1):

May it help someone, as we know, objective-c can easily call c++ methods, so we can use like this:

```
jsval ret;
ScriptingCore::getInstance()->evalString("CommonFun.setDiamond(88)", &ret);
```

and dont forget include head file, for cocos2d-x 3.8:

```
#include "cocos/scripting/js-bindings/manual/ScriptingCore.h"
```

Comment: Hi I am using cocos 2d-js 3.5 is there any way by which we can call js from objc code

Comment: can call that from any thread? or performFunctionInCocosThread should be used?

Answer (score 0):

1:how js call objc methods like this, js call only static method

```
(1)//NativeOcClass.mm  filename
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NativeOcClass : NSObject
+(BOOL)callNativeUIWithTitle:(NSString *) title andContent:(NSString *)content;
@end

@implement NativeOcClass
+(BOOL)callNativeUIWithTitle:(NSString *) title andContent:(NSString *)content{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:content delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertView show];
    return true;
}
@end

(2)for js file
var ret = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("NativeOcClass", 
                                           "callNativeUIWithTitle:andContent:", 
                                           "cocos2d-js", 
                                           "Yes! you call a Native UI from Reflection");
```

2:objc call js method

```
(1)js method,e.g.//Test.js
var Test={
          myMethod:function(){
              console.log("call js");
              }
          }
(2)objc //filename.mm
#include "cocos/scripting/js-bindings/manual/ScriptingCore.h"
....
-(void)callJsMethod
{
   jsval ret;
   ScriptingCore::getInstance()->evalString("Test.myMethod()", &ret);
}
```

Comment: I got compile error for this one.   ScriptingCore::getInstance()->evalString("Test.myMethod()", &ret);   But if I use jsval ret;
   ScriptingCore::getInstance()->evalString("Test.myMethod()"); it will be OK.

Comment: Do I need to specify the path to the js file? I did the same but the error log says there's no such method found.