# Change html text color without reloading the webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

I'm wondering how can I change the html text color without reloading the webview because with the code I'm using currently, when I scroll down the webview that's holding the html file then click the button that I set to change the html text color, the page jumps again to the beginning of the html file. I think that happens because the webview is being reloaded every time I click the button. What do you thinks guys?

The code I'm using

```
NSString *myHtmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlName ofType:@"htm"];

NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myHtmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body  text=\"#000000\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", text] baseURL: nil];
```

I don't have any experience in javascript so if you can simplify your answer, it would be very helpful.

Comment: post the code of button. is it href or button or submit? does it have # as the URL. then the page will scroll on top

Comment: @Godwin I'm using UISegmentedControl, and there is no code beside the one i mentioned above. Don't know if that helps :)

Comment: Its reloading you web view. You need to make a javascript call from native to change the text then. your js will change the color. link might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have noticed is that for changing the text color of an already loaded html file, using the following code is better as it doesn't cause the webview to reload. But what worth noting is that this code only worked for me when changing an already loaded html file.

```
[_myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color =\"Black\""];
```

But when I wanted to change the text color of a new html file (being loaded), the following code worked better for me.

```
NSString * myHtmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlName ofType:@"htm"];

NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",htmlFile);


[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body  text=\"#000000\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", text] baseURL: nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

when you add  tag it means webview will treat it as a new page and will reload you can achieve ur task it with javascript or jQuery :)