# How to Fetch Coordinate Value (x,y) from jQuery Code and Store in NSString?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

`div` tag is used for performing **bold**, *italic*, etc. operations in `UIWebview`. I want to fetch the position coordinates when the user touches the div tag through JavaScript/jQuery.

I found the code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#C').click(function(e) {
        var posX = $(this).position().left, posY = $(this).position().top;
        var x =  e.pageX - posX;
        var y =  e.pageY - posY;
        alert( (x) + ' , ' + (y));
    });
});
```

```css
#C { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 15px Arial; 
}
```

```html
<div id="C" style="left:500px;">
    position() <br /> 
    mouse <br/> 
    position 
</div>
```

How to store `x` and `y` coordinates from jQuery to `NSString` using string by evaluating JavaScript from string?

Comment: Improved formatting, fixed typos for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [UIWebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:), you need to use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and return a value from your Javascript function.

[This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c) has a few answers that go into pretty good detail. I suggest starting there.

**Update in response to comment:**

jQuery is simply a Javascript library. The fundamentals still apply. To return a value in jQuery (in this case, altering the function you've provided) you just need to... well... *return* the value.

```
var getCoord = function() {
    var posX = $(this).position().left, posY = $(this).position().top;
    var x =  e.pageX - posX;
    var y =  e.pageY - posY;
    return (x) + ' , ' + (y); // this is the line that returns your coordinates
};

getCoord(); // to call your function
```

Comment: I want to return the value from Jquery. How to do it. I already know for the Javascript and some functions only run fine with jquery.

Comment: See my updated answer. Returning a value is pretty standard stuff.