# Can I use F# to build a (cross-platform) library for use in an otherwise native iOS application?

Tags: ios, f#, cross-platform

Subject line pretty much describes it. I'm looking for a toolchain to build a cross-platform business logic library that would be consumed by (among others) an otherwise native iOS application.

I'm thinking about using F# for this library, as I like its functional approach and what I've read about performance seems at least reasonable.

I'm wondering how feasible it is to write this library in F# and then invoke/consume it from an otherwise native (probably Swift) application on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fable to compile your library and then write your app in React Native to consume it as a native app in iOS.  Here are some interesting things you can do with Fable.  http://www.navision-blog.de/blog/2016/08/14/fable-sudoku-creating-a-sudoku-solver-app-with-f/

If you don't want React Native, then your other option is to call the generated JS code directly from your native code, but that's a bunch of boilerplate and casting for each function call.  [How to call JavaScript Function in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c)

The solution I think you're hoping for is to be able to compile to Xamarin and use the library from an iOS app like a native library, however that's not possible.

Comment: Your last paragraph reflects the question I was asking and the answer I was afraid of. Thanks for taking the time to make that clear.

Comment: @nicka773 Sure. fwiw Xamarin has to create its own runtime, garbage collector, etc, so has to "own" the process. That's why it doesn't work as a library. Maybe someday there'll be a way around it, but I'd not bet on it anytime soon.