# UIWebView not calling my Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am aware that this question is already posted lot many times. But none of them are helping me to solve my issue. Please consider reading entire question before downvote :-)

So, for I have below lines of code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEGU9IV4SAK8"];

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegates

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString * jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test()"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString] ;


//This code is working. Able to prompt "Hello"    
//     jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('Hello');"];
//    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString] ;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{

   // ignore legit webview requests so they load normally
    if (![request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:kSchemeName]) {
        return YES;
    }


    // look at the actionType and do whatever you want here
    if ([actionType isEqualToString:kJSActionForPay]) {

        //Call objective-c method - Success 
    }

    // make sure to return NO so that your webview doesn't try to load your made-up URL
    return NO;
}
```

So, Far I have tried / understood.

[1] Call JS function only after web view loaded. (used delegate)

[2] Able to prompt "Hello" from

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('Hello')"] ;`

[3] Changes done in HTML side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
</body>
     <script> 
      function test() {
        alert("Started");
     }
     </script>
</html>
```

**Please help to find out what I am missing in HTML Side ?  or In my native Objc?**

**EDIT 1**: 
As @Andy suggested, I loaded html from local. Then I am able to call JS function "test()"

Comment: "test()" not called from native code.

Comment: does this help at all ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c

Comment: @AndyDonegan Yes, it does !!! It calls JS when html loaded from Local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the w3schools editor to be the source html for your project. The `url` you tried to visit not only contains your content but also the scripts used by w3schools. Instead, you should put your html file on your own server or a .html file inside your project. Then, you can call the `test()` method.

Comment: Hey @chengsam, you are right ! It works when the same html loaded from loal( main bundle) Thanks